# Can I change the default options for json_encode

Tags: php, json

I can't find anything in PHP's documentation about this, so it's probably not possible without wrapping json_encode in a proprietary function.

But I was wondering if I can set the default options for the json_encode function in php.ini or somewhere else?

The purpose is to always have JSON_HEX_APOS and JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK on, i.e.:

`json_encode($object)` would equal
`json_encode($object, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)`

Comment: Don't think it's possible - it'd also be fairly confusing for other developers viewing your code if you could, just wrap it in your own function and move on.

Comment: @FDL Yeah, you're right about that. Bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from editing the functions source code no, altough a function would be easy to create (as you said)

```
function j_code($object){
return json_encode($object, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Default options are there by default, so no, you can't change them. What you can do is make a wrapper function (as you already said) which automatically sets those options unless otherwise instructed.