# Is there a way to set a json_encode constant permanently?

Tags: php

I use this code:

```
json_encode($arr,JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR);
```

Works great.

Is there a way to set the `JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR` permanently (e.g. at runtime) so that even without that constant defined (i.e. `json_encode($arr);`) it will assume the constant was defined?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change the default options for json\_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556746/can-i-change-the-default-options-for-json-encode)

Comment: @El_Vanja That is an appropriate workaround, thank you.